# How can I show a LWC ToastEvent message in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-web-components, toast

I have an LWC component which has multiple `showToastEvent`s which works in Lightning Exp without any issue.

But when I am calling the same LWC component from a VF page, I am not able to see toastevent.

I know ShowToastevent is not supported in Ltng:outApp, but is there an alternative or can I replace the existing showToastEvent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [slds-toast](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/)

Then you can use `setTimeout()` to make the custom toast disappear after a few seconds

```
    handleClick(){
        let delay = 1000
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.visible = false;
        }, delay );
    }

    <template if:true={visible}>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:1rem;left:1rem;right:1rem">
            <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
                <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_default slds-box slds-box_small" style="border-color:green;" role="success">
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_large" style="color:green;">Succeeded</h2>
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:success" alternative-text="success" variant="Success" size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [ui:message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:message/documentation) component which will work in lightning out. The only thing is UI components have been deprecated but it would be a quick win.

[image]

Or, You have to use [slds -Toast](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/) in your lightning component so that it will work in visualforce page as well. check out this:- [Display and close toast in SLDS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144088/display-and-close-toast-in-slds)

Answer (score 0):

use this code snippet inside the script tag, above the `$Lightning.use` code that's it :

```
**document.addEventListener('lightning__showtoast', event => {
        sforce.one.showToast(event.toastAttributes);
    });**
```

More briefly if needed:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('lightning__showtoast', event => {
        sforce.one.showToast(event.toastAttributes);
    });
    $Lightning.use("c:YourOutApp", () => {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

The above answer has been originally given by Bartosz Śliwiński